# How to apply css to headers of a lightning:datatable?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, css, lightning-datatable

I've tried this in two ways:

First:

```
component.set("v.columns",[
            {label:'', fieldName:'edit', type:'action', class: 'cols', cellAttributes: { iconName: { fieldName: 'utility:custom_apps' }}},
...
]);
```

Second:

```
<lightning:datatable data="{! v.data }"
        class="cols table"
        columns="{! v.columns }"
        keyField="id"
        resizeColumnDisabled="true"
        hideCheckboxColumn="true"/>
    </lightning:card>
```

But neither of it works. 
Is it possible at all?

If needed, I here is my CSS as well

```
.THIS .cols {
    background-color: #16325c;
    color: white;
}

.THIS .table{
     text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should not be super difficult give your datatable a class e.g. `table-test`
then in a style section of a component add

```
.THIS .table-test thead th span {
background-color: #16325c;
color: white}
```

The result should be:

[image]

Bear in mind there are hover events that you also have to override.