# Change text color in header of Lightning Data Table (LWC)

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, lightning-design-system

I am trying to change the text color in a lightning data table (LWC), and I'm not having any luck. I've read several posts about changing the background color of the headers in a lightning data table, but nothing about changing the text color. See my last attempt below. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
<lightning-datatable
            class="data-table"
            key-field="id"
            hide-checkbox-column
            column-widths-mode="auto"
            columns={COLUMNS}
            data={accounts}
            onrowaction={callRowAction}
            ></lightning-datatable>
```

```
.data-table th {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply css to headers of a lightning:datatable?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/224287/how-to-apply-css-to-headers-of-a-lightningdatatable)